# Inspecting ImmutableJS objects in DevTools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, immutable.js

I've started working with [ImmutableJS](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js) and in general, really like it.

But there's one major deal-breaker - viewing ImmutableJS objects in DevTools, like a `List`, displays the `List` constructor instead of the List items. Here's an example:

[image]

Ideally, the elements of the `List` would be shown so they could be inspected.

Is there a way, other than using ImmutableJS methods like `toArray()`, to view Immutable objects in DevTools?

Comment: Yes, but I'm trying to avoid having to use methods like `toJSON()`, `toArray()`, `toObject()`, etc. Ideally a breakpoint with Watch on a ImmutableJS variable would work too. But currently that will result in the `List` constructor as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/immutablejs-object-format/hgldghadipiblonfkkicmgcbbijnpeog) that does what you want. It's also available on GitHub: https://github.com/andrewdavey/immutable-devtools

Essentially, it turns this:

[image: Before]

into:

[image: After]

Comment: I saw this earlier today. Does it work as a standalone extension, or does it require the `npm` package be installed too?

Comment: It works as a standalone extension. But make sure you check "Enable custom formatters" as specified in https://github.com/mattzeunert/immutable-object-formatter-extension